# Error setting Python interface for R code

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I'm trying to use the `rugarch` R package for my code in Python using the `rpy2` library but after running this

```
import rpy2.robjects.packages as rpackages


utils = rpackages.importr('utils')
utils.chooseCRANmirror(ind=1)

utils.install_packages('rugarch')
rugarch = importr('rugarch')
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/usr/lib/R/library/grid/libs/grid.so':
  /usr/lib/R/library/grid/libs/grid.so: undefined symbol: GEStroke
```

I've been digging to figure out how to fix this issue but haven't been able to find a way to make it work.

EDIT: I'm using R version 4.2.1

Thanks!

Comment: Does it work in R? The error looks like R dependency issue and not `rpy2` issue.